# How do I minor upgrade MySQL on Windows?

Tags: windows, mysql, php, iis-7

I currently have MySQL 5.1.35 installed on a Windows 2008 server via the MSI installer. I need to upgrade to the latest 5.1.44 to fix a bug, but docs were not clear on how to do this.

I ran the MSI installer, but it did not give me any upgrade option so I quit it. I am weary because it's a production machine with many PHP websites running on it. Also, my data directory is not the default one, it's kept on another partition.

How can I upgrade it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't come up with any other options you could

- backup your config
- backup your databases
- uninstall mysql
- install new version
- restore configuration
- restore data

You should do the first two steps even if you find a way to upgrade.

Comment: No need to uninstall. Just install over the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

- Backup the databases first, as there is **always** a possibility of something going wrong.
- Stop the MySQL service.
- Backup the MySQL application folder tree.
- Install the new version over the top on the old one.
- Restart the service.

Unless something bad happened, as we all know can happen with software, you'll be up and running with the latest version. If something does go wrong just uninstall the new version and restore your backups.